# JPA MySQL exponentially slower

Tags: mysql, performance, jpa

I have a problem when switching pages on my webapp. 
When I switch between pages (Making requests against my DB), the response time becomes exponentially slower. See for example output from chrome, where I switch between two pages repeatedly:

[Chrome screendump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lfezq.png)

But it is session specific. If I open another window/browser, the problem isn't there (though still in the other session), until I start switiching pages again.

When the page loads, this is called:

```
    ActualTestGrabber actualTestGrabber = new ActualTestGrabber();
    concretetest = actualTestGrabber.getById(80);
```

And for the "grabber":

```
public Concretetest getById(int tf){

    EntityManager manager = getManager();
    TypedQuery<Concretetest> query = manager.createQuery("SELECT w FROM Concretetest w WHERE w.id=" +tf ,Concretetest.class);
    Concretetest result = query.getSingleResult();

    Close();
    return result;      
}
```

And the getManager and close:

```
@Transactional
public EntityManager getManager(){
    emfactory =  Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory( "DSLTestV4" );
    entitymanager = emfactory.
            createEntityManager( );
    entitymanager.getTransaction( ).begin( );
    return entitymanager;

}

@Transactional
public void Close(){
    entitymanager.getTransaction().commit();
    entitymanager.close();
    emfactory.close();
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Why does the querytime get exponentially worse?
Really hope someone can help.

EDIT:

[SQL Code for Concretetest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dI2AU.png)

Best regards
Benjamin

Comment: I can't explain the exponential issue - you'll need to look into profiling to see what could be taking the time.  There doesn't seem to be a need to start a transaction, or close out the Factory each time you want a simple fetch of a single Concretetest entity.  Performing this repeatedly might drag on your system resources, as processing the persistence unit might be what is slowing you down, and try to statically hold onto factories.

Comment: Show us the SQL (aside from the wrapper code).

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE Concretetest` -- It sounds like there is no index on `id`?

Comment: @Chris I see what you mean. I tried, just to see if this was the problem, to put the manager and the factory in a singleton. This delayed the problem a good deal, but didn't solve it completely - see new screen dump: http://tinypic.com/r/ivvf28/9. But it definitely helped!

Comment: @RickJames see updated post :)

Comment: What are the `SELECTs`, etc?

Comment: You will have to still profile to tell, but I wouldn't use an EntityManager in a singleton.  An entityManager is meant to span the life of a transaction, and anything read through it is kept in memory and checked for changes when the persistence unit needs to synchorize with the database.  If you are going to use a single EM, you will want to clear it on occasion to release these resources.  Your system and configuration itself needs to be looked at, as I don't know why you would use entitymanager.getTransaction( ).begin( ); within a method marked with @Transactional.

Comment: Thanks Chris! I'm new to java and webdev, I'm an old C guy, really appreciate your feedback, and I'm gonna do some fixes tommerow. Really, thanks mate!